# Building Mailcore2 on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, mailcore2, mailcore

I'm trying to build the mailcore2 library on linux (Ubuntu 18.04) but having a hard time. (Mostly) following the directions on their repo here: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-linux/README.md

So first I install dependencies (that all goes fine):

```
sudo apt-get install libctemplate-dev libicu-dev libsasl2-dev libtidy-dev \
    uuid-dev libxml2-dev libglib2.0-dev autoconf automake libtool cmake
```

Then it instructs how to build libetpan, but I'm using the updated instructions from the libtepan repo: https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan:

```
git clone https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan
cd libetpan
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Finally I try to build MailCore:

```
git clone https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2
cd mailcore2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

But no matter what commit I'm using, I always get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/<USER>/mailcore2/src/core/basetypes/MCString.h:7:0,
                 from /home/<USER>/mailcore2/src/core/basetypes/MCData.cpp:24:
/home/<USER>/mailcore2/build/src/include/MailCore/MCICUTypes.h:16:25: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef short unsigned int UChar’
 typedef __CHAR16_TYPE__ UChar;
                         ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/unicode/utypes.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/unicode/ucsdet.h:24,
                 from /home/<USER>/mailcore2/src/core/basetypes/MCData.cpp:15:
/usr/include/unicode/umachine.h:347:22: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef char16_t UChar’
     typedef char16_t UChar;
                      ^~~~~
src/CMakeFiles/MailCore.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/MailCore.dir/core/basetypes/MCData.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/MailCore.dir/core/basetypes/MCData.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/MailCore.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/MailCore.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been using it on iOS (via CocoaPods) for a while, but wanted to move my email functionality to the server-side. I opened an issue on Github, but no traction yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/home/<USER>/mailcore2/build/src/include/MailCore/MCICUTypes.h`

replace:

```
typedef __CHAR16_TYPE__ UChar;
```

with:

```
typedef char16_t UChar;
```

then run:

```
make clean
make
```

Comment: I don't know C++, so I'm a little lost, but how would I fix this in the source code? It seems like that header file only exists after the first attempt to build.

Comment: Or rather, after running cmake

Comment: Hmm, and now I keep getting the following: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licule" I checked and libicu-dev is definitely installed. (This is on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 vm, btw.)